# How do I get the bitmap of an image?

Tags: android, image, kotlin, bitmap

In my `onActivityResult` function, I have the following lines of code:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        val foodBitmap = Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.requireNonNull(data)!!.extras)!!["data"] as Bitmap?
        food_image.setImageBitmap(foodBitmap)
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

For `foodBitmap` it's inferred type is `Bitmap`, but I need to ensure that it's type is `Bitmap` for another function that I'm using which expects a parameter of type `Bitmap`. I currently can't pass `foodBitmap` into that function because it expects a `Bitmap` and doesn't consider `foodBitmap` to be a `Bitmap`. How do I fix that line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inferred type of `foodBitmap` is not a `Bitmap`, but nullable type `Bitmap?`. Therefore you have three options:

1. Change code of initializing `foodBitmap` to:

   ```
   val foodBitmap = Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.requireNonNull(data)!!.extras)!!["data"] as Bitmap
   ```
2. In your other function change parameter to be `Bitmap?`
   or
3. When you call that function use `let` function:

   ```
   foodBitmap?.let { otherFunction(it) }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have this :-

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && data != null) {
        val foodBitmap = data.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
        food_image.setImageBitmap(foodBitmap)
      }
}
```

You will get `foodBitmap` as `Bitmap` and you can directly pass that into your function.